# Getting a list of wifi devices in linux with open-wrt

Tags: linux, wifi, openwrt

I have a router that runs open-wrt. I need to write a script that grabs all wifi devices (NOT JUST AP) and their respective signal strength. It's also important to note that these devices may or may not be connected to my network.

So basically if there's a phone out there that's within the range of my router I want to grab its MAC and its signal strength.

all my research led me to `iw dev wlan0 scan` but unfortunately this command only returns the AP's.

I also know that airodump-ng does this but I can't really copy airodump-ng to the router. I wondering if there's an easier way of gathering this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You could use command **arp** or **cat /etc/dhcp.leases** if im correct. Check the question i just posted it might be useful for what you need.

Comment: That won't work still the devices are not connected. They're merely roaming and therefore don't have a DHCP address or an arp entry.

Comment: So if they are not connected how could you grab anything from them? That command "iw dev wlan0" works only with AP's because AP's are indeed streaming s signal so you can connect or verify it's intensity. Something like a phone is not streaming a signal or have anyway for you to connect to and check it's MAC address. Give them something to connect to and you will be able to do that.